# Java Eclipse Application Window

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

When I go into the design panel of an Application Window class and I want to put a button, or rather anything I can't put it where I want it. It let's me to choice 1 of the 5 sides(top,right,left,center) and the button is as large as the whole panel.
What can I do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using? Swing, JavaFX, SWT, JFace, Eclipse RCP? Show us your code.